# How to add asp code blocks to sharepoint 2013 page layout?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

In my SP2010 page layouts, I had code wrapped in `<% %>`, but now I am moving it to SP2013, but the html page layouts don't allow those tags. How can I add them in?

Thanks

Comment: how much code is it?

Comment: Its like 10 lines, but does the amount of code matter?

Comment: yes if it is not that much you can maybe rewrite it to javascript code?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish in those 10 lines? AFAIK this is not supported in 2013.

Comment: @RobertLindgren it's funny how the notice is actually encouraging him to ask a new question and when he does just that, he is reprimanded. :)

Comment: @uberz91 yeah the notice is not optimal when the same user posts the same question multiple times I'm afraid.. The purpose is to only have a finite set of questions on a topic to improve the overall quality of the site